# how to restrict old data into my new custom app?

Tags: opportunity, leads

I just wanted to know in case if i am creating a new app then all the data from other standard apps(Leads,Opportunities) are being seen in my Custom app , How do i restrict that old data into my new app ?

MJ

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, rohit. Can you clarify your question? Custom apps in Salesforce are just collections of tabs and objects, so you can't restrict data by age. If you're developing a 3rd party app you can restrict it in your SOQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict data from your app in this fashion. You might consider apps as additive sets of functionality, similar to how desktop applications work; any application you install on your computer has access to all of your computer's files (subject to user access restrictions, of course). Salesforce.com uses a very similar model-- any data that is visible to the currently logged in user is also available in that app. Administrators may choose to make the data available or not available based on the user's profile or by sharing settings, so assuming that the user has access to the data "outside" of your app, they also have access to the same data "inside" your app.